# Jquery найти id родительского дива

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Есть такая конструкция:

```
<div id='1' class="parent_div">
    <div class="div_child">Текст</div>
</div>
<div id='2' class="parent_div">
    <div class="div_child">Текст</div>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="add" onclick="add_div()" href="javascript:void(0)">Добавить див</a>
</div>
```

при клике на ссылку, добавляется див, аналогичный предыдущему (.div_child) и html уже выглядит так:

```
<div id='1' class="parent_div">
    <div class="div_child">Текст</div>
    <div class="div_child"></div>
</div>
<div id='2' class="parent_div">
    <div class="div_child">Текст</div>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="add" onclick="add_div()" href="javascript:void(0)">Добавить див</a>
</div>
```

Вопрос: как получить id дива-родителя для добавленного дива? Див может быть добавлен несколько раз, а так же может быть добавлен и для дива с id=2.

**UPD:** верхние примеры привел для простоты восприятия. Вот рабочий код:

```
<div style="" id="basis_position_id_4" class="basis_position_class"> 
    <div class="basis_child">
        <div class="basis_name">Базис 1 <a class="add" href="#">(удалить)</a></div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="required">Название<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" value="DAP граница Республики Беларусь 1 3" style="width:100%" maxlength="255" class="title_input" id="4">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="required">Комментарий<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" value="(при поставке товара на территорию Российской Федерации и Казахстана);" style="width:100%" class="comment_input" id="4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="basis_child_new" id="element1">
        <div class="basis_name" id="element2">Базис 2 <a class="add" href="#">(удалить)</a></div>
        <div class="row" id="element3">
            <label class="required">Название<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" value="" style="width:100%" maxlength="255" class="title_input" id="">
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="element4">
            <label class="required">Комментарий<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" value="" style="width:100%" class="comment_input" id="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Это код уже с отработавшей функцией `add_div();`
Вот и сама функция:

```
function add_div() {
    var i = $('.basis_position_class').children('.basis_child').length+1;
    obj=$('.basis_position_class');

    $('.basis_position_class').append("`<div id='element1' class='basis_child_new'><div id='element2' class='basis_name'>Базис "+i+" <a href='#' class='add'>(удалить)</a></div><div id='element3' class='row'><label class='required'>Название<span class='required'>*</span></label><input id='' class='title_input' type='text' maxlength='255' style='width:100%' value=''></div><div id='element4' class='row'><label class='required'>Комментарий<span class='required'>*</span></label><input id='' class='comment_input' type='text' style='width:100%' value=''></div></div>`");

    id = $('.basis_child_new').parent().attr('id');
    alert(id);
}
```

В данном примере я получаю id родительского элемента, но если я после этого добавлю вызову эту функцию для другого дива, то я опять же получу этот же id, вместо тогоЮ который соответствует другому диву.

Comment: @makbeth, покажите, пожалуйста, код функции **add_div()**

Comment: Добавил внизу. Извиняюсь за форматирование, но лучше здесь сделать не получилось.

Comment: так вы же сами генерируете родительский элемент здесь... зачем вы так странно получаете его id..., если же вы почему-то хотите его из html брать, сделайте сначала jquery элемент типа так (data - ваша длинная строка) :

   var toadd=$(data),
       id=toadd.find('.base_child_new').parent().attr('id');
   $('.basis_position_class').append(toadd)

а вообще вы скорее всего хотите что-то дурацкое сделать, т.е. обращаться к этому элементу по id, почему-бы не хранить сам элемент ?

Answer (score 1):

Ежели новоявленные элементы принадлежат одному лишь родителю (как в вашем простом примере), то jQuery код будет следующим `$(this).parent();`. А чтобы узнать его аттрибут `id` или другой прочий, то можно воспользоваться конструкцией jQuery `attr`, например `$(this).parent().attr("id");`. Подробнее вы можете узнать здесь [jquery-docs.ru](http://jquery-docs.ru)